# Residue theorem and combinatoric identities 2

Tags: calculus

[image]

I don't quite follow the steps as highlighted, as the expansion of terms to get the result doesn't seem to make sense to me. Will appreciate to see how they can be broken down thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The first highlighted part follows from [Cauchy's Integral Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula):

$$\frac1{2\pi i}\oint_C\frac{(1+z)^{2n}}{5^nz^{n+1}}dz=\frac{g^{(n)}(0)}{n!}\;,\;\;\text{with}\;\;g(z):=\frac{(1+z)^{2n}}{5^n}$$

and the second one from the geometric series formula:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{(1+z)^2}{5z}\right)^n=\frac1{1-\frac{(1+z)^2}{5z}}=\frac{5z}{3z-z^2-1}$$